# How to control color bar min and max in StreamPlot

Tags: plotting, color, legending

I have the following code

```
R = 0.5
\[Alpha] = 90
x2 = Cos[\[Alpha] Degree] R
y2 = Sin[\[Alpha] Degree] R
EField[x_, y_, x0_, y0_, q_] = 
 q {x - x0, y - y0}/((x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2)


StreamPlot[
 EField[x, y, -R, 0, 2] + EField[x, y, x2, y2, 6], {x, -R*1.1, 
  R*1.1}, {y, -R*1.1, R*1.1}, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Below]]
```

Which provides the following plot:

[image]
[image]

You can see because of the asymptotes it is taking a maximum value that is so large that all other values become blue. Is there a way to manually change the colorbar range so that the min and max are more reasonable and thus more detail can be seen?

I've tried to add a `PlotLegends-> BarLegend[...]` via this [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/179602/75556) but it doesn't seem to change the actual plot. Any advice is appreciated. :)

Comment: We cannot reproduce your plot since you have not defined `x2` or `y2`

Comment: Whoops, sorry bob. It was inside of a `Manipulate` and so I tried to include just the relevant part. I'll update now. Thank you.

Comment: Should be correct now.

Comment: I'm not going to change it at this point. But if anyone wants to copy this in the future for the purpose of displaying electric fields, please note: I did not divide the electric field formula but the radius and so it is incorrect. It should be divided by `((x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2)^(3/2)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One method would be to use a logarithmic scale for the arrow colors. Unfortunately it seems that `StreamPlot` does not support `ScalingFunctions`, but you can build your own color scale and legend by slightly adapting [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123441/73380) answer,

```
{min,max}={0.3,990};
sf=Log[#/min]/Log[max/min]&;
isf=InverseFunction@sf;

StreamPlot[
  EField[x, y, -R, 0, 2] + EField[x, y, x2, y2, 6], 
  {x, -R*1.1, R*1.1}, {y, -R*1.1, R*1.1}, 
  StreamColorFunctionScaling->False,
  StreamColorFunction->Function[ColorData["Rainbow"][sf@#5]],
  PlotLegends->
    BarLegend[{"Rainbow",{min,max}},
      ScalingFunctions->{sf,isf},
      ColorFunctionScaling -> True
    ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Hausdorff, this should work for what I need! Cheers!