# Modify the range of the color function in a StreamPlot, and add the corresponding ColorBar in the legend

Tags: plotting, color, legending, rescale

Hello I'm trying to manually clip the scale of the colors for the streamlines in StreamPlot. The problem is that at the origin the velocity goes to infinity and that throws off any attempt to rescaling. I've already tried modifying the RegionFunction... to no avail.

This is the default output:

```
StreamPlot[{-(y/(2 \[Pi] (x^2 + y^2))), x/(2 \[Pi] (x^2 + y^2))}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Stream Plot with color issue]

I have managed to somewhat achieve a working example:

```
StreamPlot[{-(y/(2 \[Pi] (x^2+y^2))),x/(2 \[Pi] (x^2+y^2))},{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3},RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,vx,vy,n},x^2 +y^2>0.1],PlotLegends->Automatic,StreamColorFunction->(ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[Norm[{#3,#4}],{0,0.00005}]]&),StreamColorFunctionScaling->False]
```

[image: Rescaled colors on StreamPlot, missing colorbar]

However I still had to fiddle with the Rescale values, 0.00005 is somewhat arbitrary and it does not tell me what is the actual value assigned to red or above. The plotlegend (ColorBar) then has to be inserted manually and I don't know how to do that. What I would like is a simple command to say:  "Set Color Range to -> {vmin,vmax}" in this case the values I'm interested are {0,0.35} and then display the color bar with correct values as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution

```
bar = BarLegend[{(ColorData["Rainbow", #] &), {1/(2 Pi Sqrt[3^2] ), 
    1/(2 Pi Sqrt[0.15^2])}}]; StreamPlot[{-(y/(2 \[Pi] (x^2 + y^2))), 
  x/(2 \[Pi] (x^2 + y^2))}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 StreamColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow", 1/( Norm[{#1, #2}])] &),
  PlotLegends -> Placed[bar, Below], StreamPoints -> 30, 
 StreamColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: This works well in version 12.3. I want to understand what is the code actually doing. What are the inputs at the BarLegend, and how did you arrive at the `{1/(2 Pi Sqrt[3^2]), 1/(2 Pi Sqrt[0.15^2])}` values?

Comment: Also, how do `StreamColorFunction-> (ColorData["Rainbow", 1/(Norm[{#1, #2}])] &)` and our previously defined Bar legend will interact? Thank you!

Comment: @MichelG There are 3 functions to visualize streamlines in a given color data "Rainbow". First is `StreamPoints -> 30` (we using it instead of `RegionFunction`) that makes empty region around singularity `x=0, y=0`. Second is `StreamColorFunction` that generates color of streamlines with a rule of vector field singularity. And the last one is  `PlotLegends` that makes bar legend with the scale of  the field variation on this picture.

Answer (score 5):

If your plot spans several orders of magnitude, you might also consider using a logarithmic scale, as in [these](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36830/73380) [examples](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262166/73380).

```
{min, max} = {1/100, 1};
sf = Log[#/min]/Log[max/min] &;
isf = InverseFunction@sf;

StreamPlot[
  {-(y/(2 \[Pi] (x^2 + y^2))), x/(2 \[Pi] (x^2 + y^2))}, 
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  StreamColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  StreamColorFunction -> Function[ColorData["Rainbow"][sf@#5]], 
  PlotLegends -> 
    BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {min, max}}, ScalingFunctions -> {sf, isf}, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
]
```

[image]

The options `ScalingFunctions` and `ColorFunctionScaling` are not officially supported for `BarLegend`, and are therefore higlighted red in notebooks (which was also seen in the answers of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36830/73380) post). However, at least in versions 12.0 and 13.0 they still work, as they are options of the internal `` Charting`iBarLegend ``.

Comment: It is a nice solution (+1). It looks like in version 13 there is support for arbitrary scaling function as it shown in my answer.

Comment: This looks very practical and useful, pretty much what I need, however BarLegend in my version (12.3) doesn't recognize those functions. I will see if I'm able to update my version. Thank you!

Comment: @MichelG In version 12.2 it seems to work fine. Mathematica highlights ```ScalingFunctions``` and ```ColorFunctionScaling``` as invalid options for ```BarLegend```, though they seem to be doing their job, as the result is the same as in version 13.0.Maybe they are just undocumented

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks :) (though it is essentially a copy of my other answer) I am not sure I understand your point about the scaling function, though. After all, for ```Streamplot``` I am essentially doing the same thing as you just with a logarithmic function in ```ColorFunctionScaling```, right?

Comment: @Hausdorff I like your approach. But why it is  working in v.12.3 with a message `InverseFunction::ifun: Inverse functions are being used. Values may be lost for multivalued inverses.`? Also as Michel mentioned there is red color for `ScalingFunctions` and  `ColorFunctionScaling`. Fortunately I have v.13,  and there is also same message. But plot has been generated in v12.3 and v13 as well.

Comment: @AlexTrounev The message seems to come from some floating point inaccuracy when defining ```isf```, and you can get rid of it by using ```min=1/100```. 
The red highlighting appears, as these options do not seem to be officially supported for ```BarLegend```, and are not listed in ```Options[BarLegend]``` (the highlighting is then due to the form of ```SyntaxInformation@BarLegend```). 
However, ```ScalingFunctions``` and ```ColorFunctionScaling``` are options for the internal object ```Charting`iBarLegend```, which is why they still work.